# How to express the multiplication of a column of a matrix by a scalar as a transformation per similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}n^2 & 1 & 1 &\cdots & 1 \\ -1 & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\-1 & 0 & 3 & \cdots & 0
\\\vdots & \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\ -1 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots & n\end{bmatrix}$$
In other words, is the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ such that $a_{11}=n^2, a_{ii}=i, a_{i1}=-1=-a_{1i}$ for $i=2, \dots, n$. I want to find a matrix $D$ such that
$$D^{-1}AD=\begin{bmatrix}n^2 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ -\epsilon & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\-\epsilon & 0 & 3 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\ -\epsilon & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & n\end{bmatrix}$$
for a certain $\epsilon >0$. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: It is not possible. For $n=2$, the existence of such a matrix $D$ would imply that the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{4&1\\-1&2}, \quad \pmatrix{4&1\\-\epsilon & 2}
$$
are similar. We can see that these matrices are not similar because their determinants are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that $A$ is a diagonally dominant matrix and therefore is non-singular. Now, let's suppose the statement in question is true. Since determinant is a similarity invariant, we must have $|A| = |Q|$ where $Q$ is the second matrix in your question and $|.|$ is the determinant function. You can rewrite $Q$ as
$$
Q = AP + n^2(1-\epsilon )e_1e_1^T
$$
Where $P$ is the diagonal matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{llll}
\epsilon & & & \\
& 1 & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
and $e_1 = \left[\begin{array}{lllll}1 & 0 &\ldots & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]^T$.
Computing the determinant of $Q$ and equating it with $|A|$ gives: <sup>[1]</sup>
$$
|Q| = \epsilon |A|(1+(n^2(1-\epsilon ))e_1^T P^{-1}A^{-1}e_1) = |A|
$$
This implies, after some calculations:<sup>[2]</sup>
$$
|A| = n^2 n!
$$

which **cannot be true for any n**. The reason is that $|A| = n^2 n! + n!(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n})$.  <sup>[3]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] <sub>use the identity: $\operatorname{det}\left(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{c d}^{T}\right)=\operatorname{det}(\mathbf{A})\left(1+\mathbf{d}^{T} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{c}\right)$</sub></sup>

<sup>[2] <sub>use adjoint formula for the inverse of $A$ and realize that $e^T_{1} X e_1$ is the (1,1) element of a matrix</sub></sup>

<sup>[3] <sub>You can derive this by decomposing $A$ as $A = U - {p} e^T_{1}$ where $U$ is the upper-triangular part of $A$ and $p = [0,1,...,1]^T$</sub></sup>